# Using SNMP set message on MS Windows SNMP agent

Tags: snmp, agent, winsnmp

State of TCP connection (tcpConnState) is writable per RFC 1213. Everything is fine when i reset this tcpConnState value from established (5) to deleteTCB (12) with SNMP set message with SNMP Agent from DMH software (http://www.dmhsoftware.com/snmp.html). 
But i cannot perform the SNMP Set command on that variable with Windows SNMP service (install SNMP service on Windows XP, Vista or Win 7; doing several configuration steps for community string etc). 
I guess that's due to some limitation/implementation policy on Windows SNMP service, but could not find any proof for that. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows SNMP agent, you need to check the SET community name. It must be used to set objects to values you want. Otherwise, operations can fail.

Besides, not all SNMP agents are 100% compliant to RFCs. You need to test them out and never assume "they work that way by default".